# Why my tabular does not have the padding

Tags: tables, spacing, moderncv

I tried to insert on a document a table (`tabular`) but the rendering of the code is a table without padding. Where is the error?

code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}

\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.77]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
```

...

```
\cvitemwithcomment{}{
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\toprule
XXXXXXXXXX & MMMMMM       & XXXXXXXXXXX & MMMMMMMM \\ \midrule
Lorem      & Ipsum       & dolor       & sit      \\
amet,      & consectetur & adipiscing  & elit.    \\
Aenean     & a           & lacus       & sit      \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
{}
```

the result is:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you use and how the `\cvitemwithcomment{}` macro is defined. Please also tell us which commands you execute -- or which font-related package(s) you load -- to switch to a sans-serif font. And, do tell us if the length parameter `\tabcolsep` is reset (to zero length...) anywhere in your document.

Comment: It is possible the length `\tabcolsep` was somewhere reset to 0pt.  You can try `\tabcolsep=1ex\relax` just prior to `\begin{tabular}` to see if it has an effect.

Comment: Remove the `@{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `\cvitemwithcomment`, I'm assuming you're using the [`moderncv` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv).

The length responsible for the gap between columns in a `tabular` is `\tabcolsep`. This is *defined* in [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co) - the LaTeX kernel - but is specifically *set* within the document class that you use. For example, [`article`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co) uses

```
\setlength\tabcolsep{6\p@}
```

However, `moderncv` has the following comments inside [`moderncv.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncv.cls):

```
% not set on purpose
%\setlength\arraycolsep{5\p@}
%\setlength\tabcolsep{6\p@}
%\setlength\tabbingsep{\labelsep}
```

So, it purposely does not set any changes to `\tabcolsep` (and others), keeping them at their default length which is `0pt` when it is defined.

If you wish to have some padding, you have the following options:

1. Add

   ```
   \setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}
   ```

   anywhere in your preamble. Note that this may affect other components constructed by the document class wherever it uses a `tabular`.
2. Use

   ```
   \begingroup
   \setlength{\tabcolsep}{6pt}
   % <your tabular content>
   \endgroup
   ```

   to localise the scope of the `\tabcolsep` changes to the specific `tabular` where you want to use it.

Option 2 would be advisable, since the class uses `tabular`s quite regularly.

Comment: Option 2 could be better implemented with a new environment